# Instantiating an object in a function - Python

Tags: python, oop, instantiation

I'm relatively new to python but think I have a decent enough understanding, except for (apparently) the correct way to use the "import" statement. I assume that's the problem, but I don't know.

I have

```
from player import player

def initializeGame():
    player1 = player()
    player1.shuffleDeck()
    player2 = player()
    player2.shuffleDeck()
```

and

```
from deck import deck

class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
        self.deck = deck()

    def drawCard(self):
        c = self.deck.cards
        cardDrawn = c.pop(0)
        self.hand.append(cardDrawn)

    def shuffleDeck(self):
        from random import shuffle
        shuffle(self.deck.cards)
```

But when i try to initializeGame() it says "player1 has not been defined" and I'm not really sure why. In that same file if I just use "player1 = player()" then it woks perfectly fine but it refuses to work inside of a function.  Any help?

EDIT: ADDING THINGS THAT WEREN'T INCLUDED BEFORE

```
class deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def viewLibrary(self):
        for x in self.cards:
            print(x.name)

    def viewNumberOfCards(self, cardsToView):
        for x in self.cards[:cardsToView]:
            print(x.name)


from deck import deck

class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
        self.deck = deck()

    def drawCard(self):
        c = self.deck.cards
        cardDrawn = c.pop(0)
        self.hand.append(cardDrawn)

    def shuffleDeck(self):
        from random import shuffle
        shuffle(self.deck.cards)
```

and the traceback error is

```
player1.deck.cards

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    player1.deck.cards
NameError: name 'player1' is not defined
```

Comment: Does it really say that `player1` (rather than `player` without `1`) is undefined? This is one reason you should include a full traceback...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    player1.deck.cards
NameError: name 'player1' is not defined

If i try player1.deck.cards which should return "[]" that's the full traceback I get, my apologies for not including it

Comment: @CarlReyes The code given in the error is not in the code you gave us.

Comment: Then you did not show your actual code, or at least not enough of it. Please add what's missing.

Comment: Also note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends `CapWords` be reserved for class names, while `lowercase_with_underscores` is used for local variables, function names, etc... It makes your code significantly more readable to conform to this.

Comment: Please add your traceback to your original submission, as it is hard to read as a comment. Also, please add the module name to each block of code you have listed, and consider including the `deck.py` module you've imported in (what I assume is) `player.py`.

Comment: The line is still not in the code you have given us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    player1.deck.cards
NameError: name 'player1' is not defined
```

This shows the line where the error is thrown: `player1.deck.cards`. Said line is not in the code you gave us so we can only make assumptions on why you get the exception.

However, it is very likely, that your script looks somehow like this:

```
initializeGame()

# and then do something with
player1.deck.cards
```

This however does not work, as `player1` and `player2` are only local variables inside the `initializeGame` function. As soon as the function returns no more references to them are left and they are most likely pending for garbage collection.

So if you want to access those objects, you have to make sure that they stay around. You could do this by having the variables globally, or you could simply return them from your `initializeGame` function:

```
def initializeGame():
    player1 = player()
    player1.shuffleDeck()
    player2 = player()
    player2.shuffleDeck()
    return player1, player2
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```
player1, player2 = initializeGame()
```

And have local references to the created objects.

Or even better, create an object that represents the whole game, where the players are instance variables:

```
class Game:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.player1 = player()
        self.player1.shuffleDeck()
        self.player2 = player()
        self.player2.shuffleDeck()
```

Then you can just create a `Game` instance and access the players using `game.player1` or `game.player2`. And of course, having an object for the game itself allows you to encapsulate a lot game related functions into the object as well.

Answer (score 4):

I presume that the code that is referencing player1 is outside the function.  Variables defined inside a function are local to it, and are destroyed when the function call ends.

You need to either declare player1 and player2 as global variables, or wrap the whole thing in a class and make them attributes of the class instance.